# Angularjs: Reset specific $scope object properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm having 2 select fields and number of input fields as scope object properties

```js
  $scope.resetAll=function(){
      $scope.tableVal=0;
     };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<select ng-model="tableVal.portfolio" ng-change="getProjectPhase(tableVal.portfolio)" class="form-control portfolioSelect" id="sel1" style="margin-top: -3px;">
     <option>blah blah<option>
     
      <select ng-model="tableVal.project" ng-options="v as v for (k,v) in selectOptions" class="form-control projectPhaseSelect" id="sel3" style="margin-top: -3px;">
         <option>blah blah<option>
        </select>
  
   <td>$<input  id="testingInput" type="number"step="0.02" ng-disabled="!tableVal.project" ng-model="tableVal.Prevention"> </td>
  
  
   <td>$<input  id="testingInput" type="number" step="0.02" ng-disabled="!tableVal.project" ng-model="tableVal.Appraisal"> </td>
  
  
   <td>$<input  id="testingInput" type="number" step="0.02" ng-disabled="!tableVal.project" ng-model="tableVal.InternalFailure"> </td>
  
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="resetAll()"style="margin-top: -11px;">RESET</button>
```

when i click reset button the  **$scope.tableVal=0;** resets all the field, but in my case i want select values not to be replaced, i somehow managed to get the values and set it manually, but no use

```js
function(portfolio,project){
          
           $scope.tableVal=0;
          $scope.tableVal.portfolio=portfolio;
                $scope.tableVal.project=project;
}
```

how to resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In resetAll method, reset all the values except those which are bind to the select.

```
for (var key in $scope.tableVal) {
    if (key !== 'project' && key !== 'portfolio') {
        $scope.tableVal[key] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: never thought about this.. greatttt